# How to link to another page based on a returned value

Tags: javascript, html, gwtbootstrap3

I have just started using GWTBootstrap. I have set up my login page and now I want to:

- If login was unsuccessful stay on page
- If value returned from the database is `"1"` go to `htmlpage1.html`
- If value returned from the database is `"2"` go to `htmlpage2.html`

In this way if the wrong login information is entered I do not go to the next page and, if successful login, people with different access levels are presented with different information.

Is there a tutorial that covers this please?

My html code is:

```
  <form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
    <button id="SignIn" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        document.getElementById("SignIn").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "htmlpage1.html";
        };
    </script>

  </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: sounds like an asynchronous operation, i.e., you may need to use `.promise` to act on the response.

Comment: You'll need to post to a server-side script with `AJAX`, and then return the result. Run a conditional against the result that directs accordingly. As is stated above, you'll explicitly need to *wait* for the response, which can be done with a promise :)

Comment: @RonRoyston - what is `.promise` ?

Comment: I don't think you need a `new Promise()`. In fact it won't work on IE, which is the largest desktop market. Learn AJAX.

Comment: You may want to use ajax to sending login information to server and response a redirect path to client if login success and response a error message to client if login failed. In this way, the destination of client routing can be control by server side program.

Comment: @PHPglue - *which is the largest desktop market* - Chrome commands 59.61% of Desktop browser share - IE isn't even in the top 3 - that said, IE can have Promises with an appropriate library

Comment: Well, IE is the Second Largest, anyways.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: @PHPglue [IE is sixth among browser usage worldwide](http://gs.statcounter.com/) unless you follow [this site](https://netmarketshare.com/) which says IE is second but will soon be eclipsed by Firefox. In any case, IE is being closed out by Microsoft and it won't matter much longer.

Comment: @Rob Yes! I am researching and which is why I asked "Is there a tutorial that covers this please?" I have the client side and server side code working I just need a tutorial to show me how to pass the result back to the html and then decide which html to display next (an IF statement or whatever). ;-)

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an AJAX request inside on-click method in order to get some response from a POST url, based on it, you will redirect to the correct html.

Anyway, is better to use some framework to do that.

Comment: Why would using a framework be better than writing my own code? I've done in many times over countless years. It's easy.

Comment: Is there a tutorial that shows me how to decide on which html to link to next based on the value received back from the server side?

Comment: framework because there is a lot of common cases for it solved but some of them. Anyway it's up to you. About tutorial, well, from the AJX response, server will return some value like "status=1 or status=2 or status=..." then you can just make a redirect to the correct page.